# Reconstructing daily values backwards using a final value in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This should be pretty straightforward to do in R using dplyr, but I am a bit stuck as to how exactly to do this.

I have aggregated by day a set of transaction revenues, and I want to calculate the daily balance using a final balance. In Excel this would be a trivial formula to do - input the first balance and then for subsequent rows subtract the daily revenues from the previous row's balance.

I am trying to do this in dplyr and keep hitting a wall. Any advice as to how I could achieve this would be great. I'm pretty sure you need to use lag() but I can't seem to figure out exactly how.

Sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- tibble(date = c('2018-04-03','2018-04-02','2018-04-01','2018-03-31','2018-03-30'),
        daily_spend = c(575,-5.26,-112.45,-73.5,25.6))

final_balance <- 1000
```

Here's what the data looks like:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  date       daily_spend
  <chr>            <dbl>
1 2018-04-03      575.  
2 2018-04-02       -5.26
3 2018-04-01     -112.  
4 2018-03-31      -73.5 
5 2018-03-30       25.6
```

What I would like to do would be to add an additional column 'balance' and for each row have the value be the previous balance minus the daily spend, to give a daily spend.

Here are some expected values:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  date       daily_spend   end_balance
  <chr>            <dbl>         <dbl>
1 2018-04-03      575.           1000 
2 2018-04-02       -5.26         425 
3 2018-04-01     -112.           430. 
4 2018-03-31      -73.5           542.71
5 2018-03-30       25.6          616.21
```

Here's what I have been trying, which doesn't work beyond the first two rows (due to the nature of the way lag() works):

```
x <- x %>%
  mutate(end_balance = ifelse(row_number() ==1,final_balance,0),
         end_balance = ifelse(row_number()>1,lag(end_balance)-lag(daily_spend),end_balance))
```

The results of this method:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  date       daily_spend end_balance
  <chr>            <dbl>       <dbl>
1 2018-04-03      575.       1000.  
2 2018-04-02       -5.26      425.  
3 2018-04-01     -112.          5.26
4 2018-03-31      -73.5       112.  
5 2018-03-30       25.6        73.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
mutate(x, end_balance = final_balance - cumsum(daily_spend) + daily_spend)
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I knew it would be obvious, and I am slapping my head that I didn't think to use cumsum() instead of lag()

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `final_balance` subtract the cumulative sum of `daily_spend` (lagged):

```
x %>% 
    mutate(end_balance = final_balance - cumsum(lag(daily_spend, default = 0))) %>% 
    as.data.frame()

#        date daily_spend end_balance
#1 2018-04-03      575.00     1000.00
#2 2018-04-02       -5.26      425.00
#3 2018-04-01     -112.45      430.26
#4 2018-03-31      -73.50      542.71
#5 2018-03-30       25.60      616.21
```